# remotes::install_bitbucket() stopped working

Tags: r, bitbucket, bitbucket-api, remotes

For many months now, I've been using `remotes::install_bitbucket()` from a Docker container to download a private Bitbucket repo and install an R package. March 10, it seems to have stopped working with the error:

```
Error : Failed to install 'unknown package' from Bitbucket:
  cannot open URL 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myRepoUsername/myRepo/src/HEAD/DESCRIPTION'
```

- `remotes` version is `2.3.0`
- I have not changed the Docker image, so `remotes` and everything else unchanged
- This fails from my local machine with the same error message March 11 (also `v2.3.0`)
- Bitbucket's website shows me my package is still there with no new commits

Does anyone know if this is a temporary problem, a Bitbucket API change, or something else?

All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Sorry, everyone, I ended up just resetting the password and everything worked again. I have no explanation for the issue but I found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it is related - but around that time Bitbucket changed their Authentication to use an Application Password instead of your usual password. You could try setting one up in your bitbucket account and using that to test if it works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."